# Efficiently dump certain class properties in PHP

Tags: php

I'm writing a class and I want to make a method that dumps some, but not all, of the class properties.

I'm lazy and I don't feel like writing out an array with the keys being the names of the properties, like so:

```
private $prop1;
private $dontdumpthis;
private $prop2;
public method dump() {
  return array(
    'prop1' => $this->prop1,
    'prop2' => $this->prop2,
    ...
```

I looked at `compact()`:

```
public method dump() {
  return compact(
    $this->prop1,
    ...
```

But that just returns an empty array.

Is there a simple way to specify the properties' names and values?

Comment: What's the commonality between the properties you do want to dump and the ones you don't? Any naming conventions? Or would you just list them out one by one by name?

Comment: @deceze no commonality, it's an arbitrary list. I would list them out one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This'll do in reasonably modern versions of PHP:

```
public function dump() {
    static $props = ['prop1', 'prop2'];
    return array_reduce($props, function ($r, $n) { return $r + [$n => $this->$n]; }, []);
}
```

Alternatively, this'll do too:

```
static $props = ['prop1', 'prop2'];
return array_intersect_key(get_object_vars($this), array_flip($props));
```